# Web page displays correctly in IE, Firefox, but requires zooming out in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Simple worker bee with little/no web dev experience here.

I'm having an issue with the eCommerce store I'm helping run. The page contains a Top Seller box that should be on the right side of the main content, and it appears correctly in both IE and Firefox. See [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmjX.jpg) It does not appear correctly on Chrome (checked multiple computers in store), as seen [here.](https://imgur.com/uPdyHQC) When I zoom out to 90% in Chrome, the page appears correctly. How can I correct this issue so that the web page in Chrome displays correctly at 100% zoom?

Comment: We need code, not pictures. Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: if you want **specific** help with your specific website then you need to open a bounty. since you don't have the points, please take a year off and learn how to code... you can't expect people to code for you for free

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making sure your html and body are set to full width. You could use something like this:

```
html, body {
   width: 100%;
}
```

You could also try using this meta tag in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Good luck, and if you need more specific answers, try to find some code to add to your question.